# How to release Objects stored in a TreeView from memory?

Tags: object, pointers, delphi-7, new-operator, dispose

I use Delphi 7. I create a record that stores info, and using pointers I store that record as an object in a TreeView with more than 100 items.

My problem is, how to release or eliminate all these objects from memory?

```
type
  PMyRec = ^TMyRec;
  TMyRec = record
    Tipo: string;
    parent: string;
  end;    

var    
  MyRecPtr: PMyRec;

for x := 1 to 100 do
begin
  New(MyRecPtr);
  MyRecPtr^.Tipo := '1';
  MyRecPtr^.parent := 'paul';
  Tree1.Items.AddChildObject(nil, IntToStr(x) + '-NewItem', MyRecPtr);
  ListaDePonteiros.Add( MyRecPtr ); // I use a TList to store pointers
  ListaDeObjectos.Add( MyRecPtr ); // I use a TList to store Objects
end;
```

How I try to delete them all:

```
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
  procedure EmptyTList(Var AList: TList);
  var
    intContador: integer;
  begin
    for intContador := (AList.Count-1) downto 0 do
    begin
      if Assigned(AList.Items[intContador]) then
      begin
        Dispose(AList.Items[intContador]);
        AList.Items[intContador] := nil;
        AList.Delete(intContador);
      end;
    end;
  end;
begin
  if Assigned(MyRecPtr) then
  begin
    EmptyTList(ListaDePonteiros);
  end;
end;
```

When I delete all items in the TreeView `OnDelete` event, I have this:

```
if assigned(Node.Data) then
begin
  Dispose(Node.Data);
end;
```

What I want to do is release all objects from memory!

If I dispose all objects using that list then if I delete any item from the TreeView an invalid pointer error is raised!!

Even with all pointers disposed, `MyRecPtr` still points to somewhere in memory, and `Node.Data` too!

Comment: You clearly do not understand how pointers and object ownership work.  You need to stop what you are doing and go back to basics.

Comment: so  if i use this code is enought to  release from memory all obects stored in treeviw? : procedure TForm1.Tree1Deletion(Sender: TObject; Node: TTreeNode);
begin
  if Assigned(Node.Data) then
    Dispose(PMyRec(Node.Data));
end;

Answer (score 1):

Your code is crashing because you are freeing the same memory twice, because you have not defined any clear ownership of your record instances.

Your `ListaDePonteiros` and `ListaDeObjectos` lists are redundant and can be removed. The `TTreeView` can be the owner of the records and you can simply `Dispose()` of them in the `TTreeView.OnDeletion` event and be done with it <sup>1</sup>.

```
var
  MyRecPtr: PMyRec;

for x := 1 to 100 do
begin
  New(MyRecPtr);
  try
    MyRecPtr^.Tipo := '1';
    MyRecPtr^.parent := 'paul';
    Tree1.Items.AddChildObject(nil, IntToStr(x) + '-NewItem', MyRecPtr);
  except
    Dispose(MyRecPtr);
    raise;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Tree1.Items.Clear;
end;

procedure TForm1.Tree1Deletion(Sender: TObject; Node: TTreeNode);
begin
  if Assigned(Node.Data) then
    Dispose(PMyRec(Node.Data));
end;
```

Otherwise, if you choose to keep a separate list, keep the `ListaDeObjectos` list and remove the `ListaDePonteiros` list (as there is no reason to maintain 2 lists tracking the exact same values).  You would just need to decide whether you want `ListaDeObjectos` or `Tree1` to own the records you allocate:

- If `ListaDeObjectos` is to be the owner, DO NOT call `Dispose(Node.Data)` in the `TTreeView.OnDeletion` event.

  ```
  var
    MyRecPtr: PMyRec;
    Idx: Integer;

  for x := 1 to 100 do
  begin
    New(MyRecPtr);
    try
      MyRecPtr^.Tipo := '1';
      MyRecPtr^.parent := 'paul';
      Idx := ListaDeObjectos.Add(MyRecPtr);
      try
        Tree1.Items.AddChildObject(nil, IntToStr(x) + '-NewItem', MyRecPtr);
      except
        ListaDeObjectos.Delete(Idx);
        raise;
      end;
    except
      Dispose(MyRecPtr);
    end;
  end;

  procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure EmptyTList(AList: TList);
    var
      intContador: integer;
    begin
      for intContador := 0 to (AList.Count-1) do
        Dispose(PMyRec(AList[intContador]));
      AList.Clear;
    end;
  begin
    Tree1.Items.Clear;
    EmptyTList(ListaDePonteiros);
  end;
  ```
- If `Tree1` is to be the owner, DO NOT call `Dispose(AList.Items[intContador])` in `EmptyTList()` (in fact, you can get rid of `EmptyTList()` altogether and just call `ListaDeObjectos.Clear()` when needed).

  ```
  var
    MyRecPtr: PMyRec;
    Node: TNode;

  for x := 1 to 100 do
  begin
    New(MyRecPtr);
    try
      MyRecPtr^.Tipo := '1';
      MyRecPtr^.parent := 'paul';
      Node := Tree1.Items.AddChildObject(nil, IntToStr(x) + '-NewItem', MyRecPtr);
    except
      Dispose(MyRecPtr);
      raise;
    end;
    try
      ListaDePonteiros.Add(MyRecPtr);
    except
      Node.Free;
      raise;
    end;
  end;

  procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
  begin
    ListaDePonteiros.Clear;
    Tree1.Items.Clear;
  end;

  procedure TForm1.Tree1Deletion(Sender: TObject; Node: TNode);
  begin
    if Assigned(Node.Data) then
      Dispose(PMyRec(Node.Data));
  end;
  ```

Either way, when not mass-clearing `Tree1` and `ListaDeObjectos` in one go, consider calling `ListaDeObjectos.Remove()` in the `TTreeView.OnDeletion` event to keep `Tree1` and `ListaDeObjectos` in sync when removing individual nodes:

```
procedure TForm1.Tree1Deletion(Sender: TObject; Node: TNode);
begin
  if Assigned(Node.Data) then
  begin
    // only if the TreeView is the owner...
    Dispose(PMyRec(Node.Data));

    ListaDeObjectos.Remove(Node.Data);
  end;
end;
```

<sup>1. Whenever you do `Dispose()` your record instance, make sure you type-cast *raw* pointers to `PMyRec` or else the compiler will not finalize the record's members correctly, leaking memory.</sup>